# Laravel Mail assertSent and assertQueued don't work in tests

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, swiftmailer, laravel-mail

I'm trying to test email sending on my Laravel 8 project, but the `Mail::assertQueued()` and `Mail::assertSent()` methods don't seem to work at all.

This is the test:

```php
public function test_send_simple(): void
{
    Mail::fake();

    $test_subject = $this->faker->text(25);
    ScheduledEmail::factory()->create(["status" => "queue", "subject" => $test_subject]);

    $command = $this->artisan("emails:send");

    $command->assertExitCode(0);
    Mail::assertQueued(SendableEmail::class);
}
```

The test uses an intermediate object to hold the mail (which makes a SendableEmail instance internally), and then calls the `emails:send` command, which sends all emails.

When I try this manually, it works, but when I test it, any assertion with Mail's methods fail. I'm unsure what to try next or why it wouldn't work.

Here are the relevant parts of my `env.testing`:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database  # I also tried sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MAIL_MAILER=log
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to explicitly use `run()` method. just like below.

```
$command = $this->artisan("emails:send")->run();
```